# OpenCVで特徴量マッチングを行うFlaskのWEBアプリをエックスサーバー上で作成したい

Tags: python, python3, opencv, flask, memory

OpenCVで特徴量マッチングを行うflaskのWEBアプリを作成したいです。
ローカルの仮想環境で問題なく動作するのですが、エックスサーバー上では以下のメモリエラーが発生してしまいます。

エックスサーバーのプランはプレミアムでメモリにはかなり余裕があるように思うのですが、なぜこのようなエラーが発生するのでしょうか。

```
An error occurred: OpenCV(4.9.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 702032 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
```

該当のソースコードは以下の通りです。

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():
    try:
        import cv2
        #画像を読み込む
        #画像１, 2
        img1 = cv2.imread('image_1.png')
        img2 = cv2.imread('image_2.png')
        
        #AKAZE検出器の生成
        akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create()
        #画像を読み込んで特徴量を計算する
        #kp = keypoints(特徴点), des = descriptors(特徴点描画)
        #detectAndCompute() => (kp: 特徴点の一覧, des:獲得頂点の特徴量記述子)のタプル
        
        kp1, des1 = akaze.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, des2 = akaze.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

        #特徴量のマッチングを行う
        #総当たりマッチング(Brute-Force Matcher)を生成
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
        #特徴量ベクトル同士をBrute-ForceとKNNでマッチング
        matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

        #データをマッチングの精度が高いもののみ抽出する
        ratio = 0.6
        good = []
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < ratio * n.distance:
                good.append([m])

        #対応する特徴点同士を描画する
        img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags = 2)

        #画像表示
        #cv2.imshow('img',img3)
        #画像保存
        cv2.imwrite('img_3.jpg',img3)
        #キーを押したら終了する
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
    #以下のコードでエラーの詳細が分かる！！！！    
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
    
    return render_template('home.html')
```

単純に実行した場合は、以下の大まかなエラー表示だけだったため、

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

以下のコードを追加した結果、メモリのエラーであることが分かりました。

```
except Exception as e:
return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 割り当てられたサーバによってメモリ搭載量は異なるようなので (8GB, 12GB) 、実メモリの容量も確認した方が良いと思います。 https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_server_spec.php

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/bghtrlqs4nb6rr
https://qiita.com/nagasetakuya0509/questions/39a2fc75806281ef4960

Answer (score 0):

クリティカルな回答をすることはできませんが
下記のようなアプローチ、調査の提案でコメントさせていただきます。

・サーバパネルのリソースモニターでのCPU、メモリ等の利用状況を確認

・処理画像サイズを縮小したうえでの動作確認